# Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 inputs files (one in JSON and another one in parquet), am trying to do a join on these 2 big data frames and writing the joined data frame to s3(as JSON). The job is stuck forever(at writing the joined JSON to s3). I am using 70 r3.4xlarge (slaves).

df1.rdd.partitions.size = 34234 (size ~4 TB)

df2.rdd.partitions.size = 1200 (size ~58GB)

Things I have tried but still no improvement :

Dynamic allocation with max resource set to true Static allocation : spark.executor.cores = 5

spark.executor.memory = 40G

spark.executor.instances = 209

Changing partitions, I played with partitions by setting : spark.default.parallelism and spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to 2000, 4000, 8000, 10000, 20000, 35000 but no use.

Intermediate persist – persisting (both memory_disk and disk_only types) the joined df persisting both inputs(prior to join), did some action on both dfs and then do join and write to s3

Tuning "mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize and "mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize (to 750000000).

I have tried using 30 r3.8xlarge as well. No improvement ☹

I keep getting one of these 2 errors –

```
zeppelin-interpreter-spark-zeppelin-ip-10-0-1-213.log: WARN [2019-02-12 04:54:43,437] ({dispatcher-event-loop-8} Logging.scala[logWarning]:66) - Lost task 24117.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 32666, ip-10-0-1-242.ec2.internal, executor 5): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 5 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1549914591854_0018_01_000010 on host: ip-10-0-1-242.ec2.internal. Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:435)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:471)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:487)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2234 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2234.3 in stage 15.0 (TID 136390, ip-10-0-1-56.ec2.internal, executor 8): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 8 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Slave lost
Driver stacktrace:
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1708)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1696)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1695)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
  at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1695)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
  at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:855)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1923)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1867)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:671)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:186)
  ... 82 more
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the executor is lost because of memory issues. Please try to configure the spark settings in spark-default.cfg file or try to increase the computing resources